# list free elastic ips from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I have a requirement where i need to filter out the free elastic ip addresses from AWS account that is, list only those which are not bound to any instance.

There are several filters i have seen here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeAddresses.html

but not able to figure out how only free elastic ips can be retrieved.

would be very helpful if anyone can give pointers on this.

Thanks a lot
~Yash

Comment: Free addresses will have "InstanceId": null

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks, but it doesn't seem to be working, can you pls give suggestion on this, what i tried is :

Filter filter = new Filter("instance-id").withValues("instance-id" , null);

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you pay for the IP if it's not bound to any instance. So you just get the ips: the ones that are bound are free.
You also have limits on the number of EIPs you can request.

Comment: Hi, yes i agree , but main thing I want is to get only those ips which are not attached to any instance(as I have several ips which are free), can u pls give any suggestion? would be very helpful.

Comment: when you describe in the output you will see if the ip is bound of not to an instance. that should be all you need.